# Method skips one in Arraylist

Tags: android, loops, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I have a method for every time the user clicks it goes to the next song.  this works until it gets to the last one then i get a force close i want the media player to stop when it gets to the last one not a force close

```
ArrayList<String> nextSongname = nextsonginfo.getStringArrayList("nextsong");
ArrayList<String> nextArtistname = nextsonginfo.getStringArrayList("nextartist");
ArrayList<String> nextAlbumname = nextsonginfo.getStringArrayList("nextalbum");
ArrayList<String> nextPathname = nextsonginfo.getStringArrayList("nextpath");
ArrayList<String> artworkkeyword = nextsonginfo.getStringArrayList("nextartwork");
int index = nextSongname.indexOf(nextSongname.get(IplayerActivity.pos-2));
Uri newuri = Uri.parse(artworkkeyword.get(index+counter));

songname.setText(nextSongname.get(index+counter));
artistname.setText(nextArtistname.get(index+counter));
albumname.setText(nextAlbumname.get(index+counter));
path = nextPathname.get(index+counter);
artworkimageview.setImageURI(newuri);

try{
    playAudio(path);
}catch(Exception e ){
    e.getStackTrace();
}

if(j < nextPathname.size()-1){
    counter+=1;
}else{
    index = 0;
    counter = 0;
    j = 0;
}
j++;
```

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting?  You don't quite have enough information here.

Comment: Without a stacktrace, there are too many things that can go wrong. My guess is that you play around with counters and positions too much (a lot of `-1`, `-2`, `index+counter`, .. happening in that code)

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to move the fallow code inside of the try catch:

```
songname.setText(nextSongname.get(index+counter));
artistname.setText(nextArtistname.get(index+counter));
albumname.setText(nextAlbumname.get(index+counter));
path = nextPathname.get(index+counter);
artworkimageview.setImageURI(newuri);
```

... it's possible that you are getting: index out of range exception.

Other recomendation is check the path for white spaces or null before play the audio. (sample in C#)

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    playAudio(path);
```

Note: `j` is unused.